# Insert a row with two fields from two different SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL database laid out:

[image: Database]

Now, I have trouble forming an insertion statement. I want to insert rows to `DiscussionParticipation` so that for each `Discussion` there would be two entries:

- One for the `User` who owns the related `Activity`
- One for the `User` who owns the `Response` related to the `Activity`

For example, if there were the following entries:

```
Discussion:
id: 1 | Activity_id: 1

Activity:
id: 1 | User_id: 1

Response:
id: 1 | Activity_id: 1 | User_id: 2

User:
id: 1 | username: Adam
id: 2 | username: Bill
```

In other words: User 'Adam' has created an activity in which user 'Bill' has created a response to. There exists a related Discussion for the activity.

Now, I'd like to add these two rows to the `DiscussionParticipation` table:

```
DiscussionParticipation:
User_id: 1 | Discussion_id: 1
User_id: 2 | Discussion_id: 1
```

How do I form this INSERT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of users can participate activity of discussion **union** a list of users can participate response of discussion.

```
insert into DiscussionParticipation (User_id, Discussion_id) (

    select a.User_id as User_id, d.id as Discussion_id
    from Discussion d
    inner join Activity a on (a.id = d.Activity_id)

    union

    select r.User_id as User_id, d.id as Discussion_id
    from Discussion d
    inner join Response r on (r.Activity_id = d.Activity_id)

);
```